# blur() is not triggering when I click outside the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to to create a jQuery validation, so far I have managed to addClass('has-error') to div.form-control. I'm trying to remove that class when I press TAB or click out of the input field, but my code isn't working.

HTML code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit='return false;' id="useradd">

<input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="username" id="username" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
<div class="form-group" id="useremail-div">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" id="email-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="useremail" id="useremail">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" value="" name="password" id="password" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code

```
 if ($("#username").val() == "" || $("#username").val().length < 3) {
            $("#username").addClass('error');
            return false;
        } else {
            name = $("#username").val();
            $("#username").removeClass('error');
        }
        if ($("#useremail").val() == "" || $("#useremail").val().length < 3 || !emailpatt.test($("#useremail").val())) {
            $("#useremail-div").addClass('has-error');
            $('#email-label').text('Incorrect Email Address');
            return false;
        } else {

            $("#useremail").blur(function() {
                console.log('out');
            });


        }
```

I've tried focusout() and focusleave(), nothing worked.

Comment: The event handler is in a condition

Comment: Where else should it be?

Comment: I'd suspect that event is never getting attached because one of the other conditions is evaluating to true. Try putting another console.log inside the else block to see if the event is being attached.

Comment: @garryp yes, I tried that and it's logging now. It even started triggering on .blur() and I can see the console message. But that only happens when I click submit again, it doesn't do it on the fly. I have to submit again to see if the error has been cleared or not.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put that blur triger outside of the if else like this :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#username").blur(function() {
        if ($("#username").val() == "" || $("#username").val().length < 3) {
            $("#username").addClass('error');
        } else {
            name = $("#username").val();
            $("#username").removeClass('error');
        }
    });        

    $("#useremail").blur(function() {
        if ($("#useremail").val() == "" || $("#useremail").val().length < 3 || !emailpatt.test($("#useremail").val())) {
            $("#useremail-div").addClass('has-error');
            $('#email-label').text('Incorrect Email Address');
        } else {
            $("#useremail-div").removeClass('has-error');
            $('#email-label').text('Email Address');
        }
    });
});
```

also you cant use `return false` in if else statements. Return is used in functions. And im not aware if that emailpatt is somewhere else defined. If not, just delete it and let the if look like this :

```
if ($("#useremail").val() == "" || $("#useremail").val().length < 3)
```

Comment: But I'm trying to say IF email is invalid addClass('has-error') to div.form-control ELSE removeClass('has-error'). I used console.log just to see if anything is happening, and it's not.
Your code did not work either.

Comment: Ok i understand now wait i will edit my post in a few moments to help you out :-)

Comment: @Halnex i edited my answer. Check it out now if it helps you now.

Comment: I tried that code before, it works only if I click submit again. It doesn't work on the fly, I need to work with .blur() so that when I click outside the input field, it removes the class and the error text. @Redrif

Comment: This does not work only if you click on submit again. It works when you leave the input. It adds has-error class if the username is empty or less then 3 chars. Same for the useremail. And it removes the class when the condition is met -> if it has 3 or more chars. When you click away from the input, it fires up.

Comment: I know what the code does, I wrote it. Let's say I leave both username and email blank and click submit, I get a jquery error on both fields and has-error gets added. If I fill the username field and jump to the email, I can still see the error message on username with 'has-error' class, at this point, I need to click submit so that it removes the has-error class. I need it to happen without submitting the form again.

Comment: Ok just look at this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lhvnu99y/
If you click on username and let it blank or less than 3 chars, it will add has-error class. When you put there 3 chars, the has-error class will be removed. Same goes for the useremail. Just try it in jsfiddle example :-)

Comment: I saw your code above and it kind of works but the 'has-error' class only triggers when I leave the field (blur) which means at first it won't show me the 'has-error', I need to click in and out in order to see it.

Comment: Ok so you want to add class has-error right after the element is focused right? And when pressed tab or click somewhere else it should remove the class right away? Im getting confused. Or you are trying to check the if else statements on every keypress? Or what? Im still not 100 percent sure what you want to do and why? Can you please edit the question itself somehow to make it more clear?

Comment: @Halnex any updates? Is it working now? Did you figure it out, or did my answer helped you? Let me know so if you got problem we can figure it out :-)

Comment: I was a problem with my code. I changed it entirely and used jquery.validate.min.js and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your time.